# jekyll serve only updates sass when I save the main file

Tags: sass, jekyll

I have a jekyll project that looks like this:

```
- assets
-- css
--- main.scss
-- sass
--- base
---- _root.scss
--- vendor
---- normalize.scss
```

main.scss includes the files

```
---
---
@charset "utf-8";

@import 'vendor/normalize';

@import 'base/root';
```

Here are the config.yml-settings that might be relevant

```
# Sass settings
sass:
  add_charset: true
  sass_dir: assets/sass
  style: :compressed

# Build settings
exclude:
  - Gemfile
  - Gemfile.lock
  - package.json
  - README.md
  - CNAME
  - node_modules
  - assets/sass
```

The sass works and gets generated into the right folders, but it seems like  sass only listens to updates of main.scss when I run jekyll serve I have tried putting all files in /assets/sass/ and also putting all files in assets/css/, but none of these things work either.

Comment: Have you tried removing your SASS-dir from the list of excludes?

Comment: Good idea, but it didn't work (exclude is about what files get's ouputted when building.

Comment: Hmm, could this be an issue for you, too? https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-help/issues/104#issuecomment-50486933

Answer (score 1):

I moved the files from `/assets/css/` to `/_css` and removed the setting `sass_dir:` from config.yml, this worked, not sure why, but it seems that jekyll only listens to sass changes in that folder. Hopefully this is heplpful for someone!